# Variables get overwritten in parallel stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

In the CI of a project I maintain, it is required to test the code against multiple architecures. Our Jenkins CI then uses a parallel stage to be run on multiple agents.

Emulating architectures is prohibited.

Everything has been working fine until I decided to refactor the pipeline in order to make it clearer. I have introduced definitions of variables inside the script that is looped on each agent.

I have observed strange behaviors, where those variables get overwritten in some task by a parallel one, as if those variables had a global scope ? Is there a way to make those variable completely local to the execution on a single agent ?

Here is a code to reproduce:

```
def testAgents = ["agent_1", "agent_2"]

def generateTestStage(nodeLabel) {
    return {
        stage("Tests on ${nodeLabel}") {

            node(nodeLabel) {
              withCredentials(
                [usernamePassword(
                  credentialsId: "${NODE_NAME}",
                  usernameVariable: "NODE_USERNAME",
                  passwordVariable: "NODE_PASSWORD"
                )]
              ){
                  script {
                    sh "echo ${nodeLabel}"
                    ANSIBLE_CREDENTIALS = "ansible_user=$NODE_USERNAME ansible_ssh_pass=$NODE_PASSWORD ansible_sudo_pass=$NODE_PASSWORD"

                    if (nodeLabel == "agent_1") {
                        echo "Where am I ? agent_1"
                        SOME_VARIABLE = "on agent_1"
                        HOSTS_FILE = "ansible/hosts.template.agent_1.yml"
                        sh "sleep 3"
                    } else {
                        echo "Where am I ? agent_2"
                        sh "sleep 2"
                        SOME_VARIABLE = "on agent_2"
                        HOSTS_FILE = "ansible/hosts.template.agent_2.yml"
                    }
                    sh "echo 'BEFORE SLEEP on ${nodeLabel}/${NODE_NAME}: SOME_VARIABLE ${SOME_VARIABLE}'"
                    sh "echo 'BEFORE SLEEP on ${nodeLabel}/${NODE_NAME}: ANSIBLE_CREDENTIALS ${ANSIBLE_CREDENTIALS}'"
                    sh "echo 'BEFORE SLEEP on ${nodeLabel}/${NODE_NAME}: HOSTS_FILE ${HOSTS_FILE}'"
                    sh "echo 'BEFORE SLEEP on ${nodeLabel}/${NODE_NAME}: NODE_USERNAME ${NODE_USERNAME}'"

                    sh "sleep 10"

                    sh "echo 'AFTER SLEEP on ${nodeLabel}/${NODE_NAME}: SOME_VARIABLE ${SOME_VARIABLE}'"
                    sh "echo 'AFTER SLEEP on ${nodeLabel}/${NODE_NAME}: ANSIBLE_CREDENTIALS ${ANSIBLE_CREDENTIALS}'"
                    sh "echo 'AFTER SLEEP on ${nodeLabel}/${NODE_NAME}: HOSTS_FILE ${HOSTS_FILE}'"
                    sh "echo 'AFTER SLEEP on ${nodeLabel}/${NODE_NAME}: NODE_USERNAME ${NODE_USERNAME}'"

                  }
              }
              
            }
        }
    }
}

def parallelTestStages = testAgents.collectEntries {
  ["${it}" : generateTestStage(it)]
}

pipeline {
  environment {
      PROJECT = "test"
  }
  agent none
  stages {
    stage("Testing on both agents") {
      steps {
        script {
          parallel parallelTestStages
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `NODE_USERNAME` gives the correct result, but `ANSIBLE_CREDENTIALS` will always give the credentials of the slowest agent, and `HOSTS_FILE` and `SOME_VARIABLE` will always be displayed with the value set in the `agent_2` stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be with how you are declaring the variables. In order to explicitly tell groovy to create a new variable you need to use `def`. So if you do not add `def` when creating the variable it may endup in the bindings for the current script and groovy may treat them as global variables. So try changing your variable declaration like below.

```
def ANSIBLE_CREDENTIALS = "ansible_user=$NODE_USERNAME ansible_ssh_pass=$NODE_PASSWORD ansible_sudo_pass=$NODE_PASSWORD"
```

Comment: I did try to add a `def` in the definition. But how am I supposed to `echo` it ? I keep getting `No such property: SOME_VARIABLE for class: groovy.lang.Binding` errors

Comment: It seems using a sole `def SOME_VARIABLE` and assign it later does work. I don't know why defining + assigning on the same line doesn't work though

Comment: My bad, I was defining the variable in the `if/else` condition. The solution is to declare the variable outside the condition, and assign it inside the condition.